# React putting props as variables in javascript template literals

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass a react props into a javascript template literal:

```
function Yuh(props) {
    return <a href={`javascript:console.log(${props.i})`}>{props.i} <h2>a</h2></a>
}
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Yuh i='lmao' />);
```

But I'm getting this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: lmao is not defined

I tried to replace `i='lmao'` with `i={5}` and that seems to work. How do I make it so that strings also work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lamo is string but 5 is number you need wrap lamo with quote or double quotation :

```
function Yuh(props) {
    return <a href={`javascript:console.log("${props.i}")`}>{props.i} <h2>a</h2></a>
}
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Yuh i='lmao' />);
```

if you dont wrap, browser think lamo is a variable , not a string :
i change here :

```
href={`javascript:console.log("${props.i}")`}
```